# What word should I use to mean "we will send a man to make you pay"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What term should to say this.

Imagine Chicago 1930. Gangsters charging businesses for protection. A guy misses a payment. The enforcer sends a man to get the money.

I have heard a phrase once that was something like "if you don't pay we will ..."
meaning that they will send a man, but was less formal than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I couldn't think in one word with this whole meaning, so I'll give you some sentences using your idea, it helps?

---

Mentioning the poet [Rihanna](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03Ac98B6cR4YB839ADrLRnh7uq3xA%3A1585157446512&ei=RpV7XuLtHuTR5OUPxL6l0AM&q=Rihanna&oq=Rihanna&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i273j0i67l6j0i203j0i67.20808.20808..21792...0.0..0.172.172.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.m5-oLEAlK2M&ved=0ahUKEwjiqIzUk7boAhXkKLkGHURfCToQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

```
Bitch, better have my money!
```

When you know you are in debt

```
You don't want Johnny to pay you a visit
```

Rush!

```
You have until sunday or things are going to get ugly
```

```
If you delay even 1 second, heads will roll
```

Obey

```
Do what I'm telling you to do, otherwise there will be trouble
```

Comment: hahaha. VERY GOOD!!! Thanks.